# Configure Active Directory in MVC3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, active-directory

I have a problem deploying a MVC3 project IIS server, the project runs well in my local machine, but not in the server the errors say's this

```
Parser Error Message: The supplied credential is invalid.
```

This is the line of configuration of my merbership Provider

```
<add name="MembershipADProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="AtentoCNEHoraExtra" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
```

What could be wrong???

Comment: yeap... =( It's in that pool, the application deployed well, the problem it's when I put my credentials in the logon view, throws that exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, I have to modify the identity of the process model associated with the pool .NET 4 in the configuration on my IIS

The value that has by default was `ApplicationPoolIdentity` and I have to changed to `NetworkService`

This configuration can be made in `ISS --> Application Pool ----> .Net 4---> Advanced Settings --> Process Model`

[image]

I hope that helps to others